# Visual Studio background image runs slowly

Tags: c#

i have created an application using C# that has some forms with a lot of pictures and text. The problem is that the background image seems to be affecting the performance. it looks like processing or rendering to load the form and its noticeable even at a run time.

i already tried changing the background image but still it has that rendering look. i tried removing the entire background image and it runs smoothly without it.

i captured my screen here's a [Link](https://vid.me/e/vwkE)

Comment: Is it slow just in Visual Studio or when you actually run it?

Comment: Are you loading the image(s) in asynchronously?  If not, that could be eating into your performance.  Otherwise, the size of the image(s) could also be an issue.  The amount of flashing I see in general though makes me think you have multiple timing issues going on...

Comment: @tnw in both run time and editing view.

Comment: Is the Form doublebuffered? Is the Image in the optimal pixelformat (PARGB)? What size does it have?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan i am pretty sure the background image is the issue here because it runs smoothly when i remove it. i heard about double rending. i don't know if that will help.

Comment: @TaW i dont know what doublebuffered is.

Comment: It is a Form property.

Comment: @TaW No, its set to false and the size of the image is 1280 × 800 JPEG

Comment: Setting that to true might help with all the flashing then.  Look up double buffering when you get a chance, but the idea is to write everything to an offscreen buffer, then write that whole buffer at once to prevent the user from seeing the updates occur in real time.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan well, double buffering helped a lot, at least all the flashes are gone even at run time.

Comment: @TaW Setting double buffering to true did the trick to all these flashes.

Comment: @TaW  you should make the double buffer Form an answer then so we can give you cookies.  Then again, you already have a ton of cookies lol...

Comment: @Michael, you go ahead, your exaplanation along with a link to msdn may well get you some reps points ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Taw,

[This link explains form double buffering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c(v=vs.110).aspx) for your C# application.

It allows you to write to an off-screen buffer to prevent flickering and other graphical corruption from occuring while writing directly to a form.  It is a very common technique in game and graphics development to allow very complex images to be created while prevent tearing, shearing, and other fun side effects that you can check out when you get a chance.

Comment: Double buffering did the trick, all the flashes are gone even at a run time.